# Multiple row insert into two tables avoiding loops

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a set of value which have to be inserted into two tables.Input has say 5 row and I have to insert these 5 rows into table A first.Table A has a identity column.Next i have to insert these 5 rows into table B with an extra column which is the identity from table A.
How this can be done with out using any loops?
Any help will be highly helpful.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A(COL2,COL3)
SELECT COL2,COL3 FROM #TEMP_TAB

set @identityval=@@identity 
INSERT INTO TABLE_B(COLA,COLB,COLC)
 SELECT @identityval,COL2,COL3,COL4 FROM #TEMP_TAB
```

Comment: Could you show us the SQL you have come up with so far?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert into multiple tables using a single statment.

What you could do is create an insert trigger on Table A so that after the insert occurs this performs the new insert with the identity of the value inserted into Table A and insert it into Table B.

Comment: I don't want to insert at a single go.I also can not use trigger as this will not happen at all times.Its a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution.

take max of identity column from table TABLE_A
insert new records in table TABLE_A
then insert records on TABLE_B from TABLE_A with Identity greater than last max identity.

Thanks,
Gopal

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible. 
You can get only the value from the last insert using the `@@identity` variable. This way its possible to add to multiple tables setting the right foreign key without selecting the just inserted row again using a cursor. This approach is not useful when inserting multiple rows at once.

From the [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X39476.htm):
Use the @@identity global variable to retrieve the last value inserted into an IDENTITY column. The value of @@identity changes each time an insert or select into attempts to insert a row into a table.

Here is a procedure which inserts a single row and you can use the return value to create a reference to the inserted data in another table:

```
create procedure reset_id as
    set identity_insert sales_daily on
    insert into sales_daily (syb_identity, stor_id) 
         values (102, "1349")
    select @@identity
select @@identity

execute reset_id
```